# Creating a Button (from image) in Zelle's Graphics

Tags: python, python-3.x, zelle-graphics

I have a start button image that I am trying to turn into a button in my program. However, I believe I am doing the math wrong or something wrong obviously because it's not working. Basically, what I am trying to do is if the person clicks on the button, it will initiate an if statement. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```
    #Assigning Mouse x,y Values
mousePt = win.getMouse()
xValue = startImage.getHeight()
yValue = startImage.getWidth()

#Assigning Buttons
if mousePt <= xValue and mousePt <= yValue:
    hour = 2
```

***startImage is the image I want to make a button. hour is a variable stated in other code.***

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing apples to oranges.  This line:

```
if mousePt <= xValue and mousePt <= yValue:
```

is roughly the same as saying:

```
if Point(123, 45) <= 64 and Point(123, 45) <= 64:
```

It makes no sense to compare Points to widths and heights.  You need to combine the widths and heights with the center position of the image and extract the X & Y values from the mouse position:

```
from graphics import *

win = GraphWin("Image Button", 400, 400)

imageCenter = Point(200, 200)
# 64 x 64 GIF image from http://www.iconsdb.com/icon-sets/web-2-green-icons/video-play-icon.html
startImage = Image(imageCenter, "video-play-64.gif")
startImage.draw(win)

imageWidth = startImage.getWidth()
imageHeight = startImage.getHeight()

imageLeft, imageRight = imageCenter.getX() - imageWidth/2, imageCenter.getX() + imageWidth/2
imageBottom, imageTop = imageCenter.getY() - imageHeight/2, imageCenter.getY() + imageHeight/2

start = False

while not start:
    # Obtain mouse Point(x, y) value
    mousePt = win.getMouse()

    # Test if x,y is inside image
    x, y = mousePt.getX(), mousePt.getY()

    if imageLeft < x < imageRight and imageBottom < y < imageTop:
        print("Bullseye!")
        break

win.close()
```

This particular icon shows up as a circle, the area you can click includes its rectangular bounding box, some of which is outside the circle.  It's possible to limit the clicks to exactly the visible image but that takes more work.